I want to increase the speed at which the game object moves and game object spawns at fixed interval
I am new to Unity and C# coding.
I am looking to create a small game, where I want to increase the speed at which the game object moves and game object spawns at fixed interval.
Can anyone guide me how to do it?
This is my code:
BalloonSpawner.cs
public class BalloonSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header(" Gameplay Elements ")]
    [SerializeField] GameObject balloonPrefab;

   
    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            StartCoroutine(SpawnBalloons());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnBalloons()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);

        float randomXPosition = Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f);
        GameObject balloonInstance = Instantiate(balloonPrefab, new Vector3(randomXPosition, -4.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        
    }
}

This is my BalloonMover.cs
public class BalloonMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header(" Settings ")]
    [SerializeField] public float balloonFlySpeed = 1f;
    

    
    void Update()
    {
        BalloonFlyer();
    }
    
    void BalloonFlyer()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * balloonFlySpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y > 3.5f)
        {
            PopBalloon();
        }
        HandleTouchInput();
    }

    void HandleTouchInput()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(touchPosition, Vector2.zero);

                if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
                {
                    PopBalloon();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        PopBalloon();
    }

    void PopBalloon()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    }
}

It would be great if someone could help me out, I am kind of stuck here, I tried few things but it didn't work. What I want is to increase the speed of the ballon moving and at the same time increase the spawns of balloon after a fixed interval.
For some reason I can see the variable in the code blocks but pls look at above code blocks. Thanks in advance.

Important question - do you understand the code you have, or is this just copied in?

I am new to coding but not that new, I have been learning unity for past couple of months, so yeah it was coded by me and I do understand them.

Why do you wait for the spawn rate twice? Once in Update and then again as a Coroutine? .. Go for one of them but it makes not much sense to go with both ... Besides that .. seems you already have figured out spawning in the same intervals.. now you only need to take the current velocity into account and increase velocity over time ... What exactly is the question?

I initially tried with that, but the balloon was spawning every frame since it was in update. So had add another wait in update

To increase the spawnrate at each spawn you could proceed like this :

Define few variables & fields to help you. Here i got a Transform that you can drag in to set the spawn point (create an empty game object for this) and 3 float values to define the spawn rate at start, the spawn rate multiplier each time and the minimum spawn rate time.
In the Start() method assign the spawn rate and launch the coroutine with the spawn rate value.
Then in the coroutine, first wait for the spawnrate timer, check if the coroutine need to be stopped (prevent infinite recursive) and then spawn the ballon with the help of the spawn point transform, finally you launch back the coroutine with your multiplied timer.

Here is the result :
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class BalloonSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header(" Gameplay Elements ")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject     _balloonPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _spawnPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float _baseSpawnRate = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float _spawnRateTimeMultiplier = 0.99f; 
    [SerializeField] private float _spawnRateTimeMin = 0.5f; 

    private float _spawnRate;
    private bool _breakSpawn;

    private void Start()
    {
        _spawnRate = _baseSpawnRate;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBalloon(_spawnRate));
    }

    public void StopSpawn()
    {
        _breakSpawn = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnBalloon(float timer)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);

        if (_breakSpawn)
        {
            yield break;
        }
    
        float randomXPosition = Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f);
        Vector3 spawnPosition = _spawnPoint.position + new Vector3(randomXPosition, 0, 0);
        GameObject balloonInstance = Instantiate(_balloonPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        _spawnRate *= _spawnRateTimeMultiplier;
        _spawnRate = Mathf.Max(_spawnRate, _spawnRateTimeMin);
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBalloon(_spawnRate));
    }
}

Then to increment the speed of your ballon, you can have the same system as with the spawn rate, and in your balloon you create a public float that can be modified in the spawner and is managing the speed of the balloon.
It could be like this :
[Header(" Settings ")]
[SerializeField] public float balloonFlySpeed = 1f;

public float SpeedMultiplier;

private void Update()
{
    BalloonFlyer();
}

private void BalloonFlyer()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * balloonFlySpeed * Time.deltaTime * SpeedMultiplier);

    if (transform.position.y > 3.5f)
    {
        PopBalloon();
    }
    HandleTouchInput();
}

and be modified when you spawn the balloon in the balloon spawner :
GameObject balloonInstance = Instantiate(_balloonPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
balloonInstance.SpeedMultiplier = [VALUE]

Hope this help :)

Thanks @Matteo for the answer. It works

Please mark the answer as “answered”
